# How to format whole column for an excel using axlsx (ruby)

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I am pretty new to ruby and trying to format all columns generated to text for the excel file.
I have got a function as below

```
def writeXlsx(columnNames, templateName)
        @xlsx = Axlsx::Package.new              # create xlsx doc
        @xlsx.use_autowidth = true
        @xlsxSheet = @xlsx.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => templateName)
        @unlocked = @xlsx.workbook.styles.add_style(:locked => false)       
        @xlsxSheet.col_style(0,@unlocked)
        @xlsxSheet.add_row columnNames, :types => string


        @xlsx.serialize(File.join(@outputFolder, "#{templateName}.xlsx"))

    end
```

this errors out saying col_style undefined method. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
-ela

Comment: Could you add the whole error in there? Possibly with backtrace?

Comment: E:\Ruby>ruby MyExcelCreator.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/axlsx-2.0.1/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/wor
ksheet.rb:562:in `col_style'
MyExcelCreator.rb:10:in `writeXlsx'
MyExcelCreator.rb:24:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/axlsx-2.0.1/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/wor
ksheet.rb:562:in `col_style': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodEr
ror)
        from MyExcelCreator.rb:10:in `writeXlsx'
        from MyExcelCreator.rb:24:in `<main>'

Comment: `code` @xlsx = Axlsx::Package.new              # create xlsx doc
   @xlsx.use_autowidth = true
   @xlsWb = @xlsx.workbook
   @unlocked = @xlsWb.styles.add_style(:locked => false)       
   @xlsxSheet = @xlsWb.add_worksheet(:name => templateName)
   @xlsxSheet.add_row columnNames #, :types => [:string,:string]
   @xlsxSheet.col_style(1,@unlocked)
   @outputFolder = outputFolder

Comment: I figured out the problem. It is the order in which the style was added. Now I dont get any error . But the format of the cell always remains as 'general'. I want to change the format of the column to 'text'

Answer (score 1):

Axlsx does not seem to have this option. I figured out to do it using write_xlsx gem.

```
def WriteXlsxNew(columnNames, templateName,outputFolder)
    require 'write_xlsx'
    # Create a new Excel workbook
    filename = File.join(outputFolder, "#{templateName}.xlsx")
    workbook = WriteXLSX.new(filename)

    # Add a worksheet
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(templateName)

    #  Add and define a format
    format1 = workbook.add_format(:num_format => '@')
    worksheet.set_column('A:BA',nil,format1)
    worksheet.write_row(0,0,columnNames)        
    workbook.close

end
```